# Codeigniter session not working Tablet

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, tablet

My code igniter application works fine in my PC , Laptop(browser IE11), and mobile also. But in my tablet sessions are not working. My session code are

```
$sess_array = array();
$sess_array = array(
     'id' => $row->id,
     'username' => $row->username,
     'role' => $row->role
   );
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
$data['role'] = $session_data['role'];
```

Comment: I take a guess that something wrong with your tab to make sure this can you try with another Tab device. If you have not already did this.

Comment: make sure you have loaded session library.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and check. It will work. also check error_log file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 6000;
```

Session Expiration is too big (`84200`), replace `84200` with `6000` or less, then check.